# Trouble Running Python LDAP from Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-ldap

I'm trying to run a script that uses the python-ldap module. I have already download the python-ldap module through pip:

```
$ pip install python-ldap
Requirement already satisfied: python-ldap in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-ldap)
```

But when I try and execute my script I see this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./AD_Python_LDAP.py", line 2, in <module>
    import ldap
ImportError: No module named ldap
```

Has anyone run into this problem or found a work-around? Thanks!

Comment: If I run it from the python terminal I have no issues

Comment: Your MAC has multiple versions of python installed, type `which python` in a terminal. Your script is probably using the one that doesnt have the package installed.

Comment: Problem was resolved by using sys module, and pointing to the site-packages path in my code.

import sys
sys.path = [''] + sys.path
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to install LDAP 
   ***python -m pip install python-ldap***

if you want to check the command for specific OS, Read [here](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/installing.html)

Comment: This does not help at all. OP says s/he already instlled LDAP and can not get it to work or import etc.